# Express.js keeps serving static index.html (React app) even I do not want it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have HTTP Express server running on port 8080 what normally serving on route `/` React Application (index.html) which is located in `/dist/` folder.

I have some other files in `dist` directory like eg. `503.html` (custom 503 error for proxy) and `construction.html` (when I do not want to serve React app).

But Express keeps serving me `index.html` from this `dist` directory even I want to choose in `app.get("/")` route definition.

Should I just rename file to something different from index, or it can be disabled somehow in express config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer myself:

`index.html` file can be set as ignored by `{index: false}` option:

```
app.use(express.static('dist', {index: false}));
```

This way, index.html is not served on `/` route no matter what is defined in routes below.